# Проблема с переменной в JS

Tags: javascript

```
 var type = 'reposts';

 // НЕ работает (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined)
 $('#tasks_create_box #min_price').html(config.tasks_prices['vk'].type[0]);

 // работает
 $('#tasks_create_box #min_price').html(config.tasks_prices['vk'].reposts[0]);
```

Как сделать, чтобы нерабочий вариант стал рабочим? Не догоняю :/

Comment: в структуре `config.tasks_prices['vk']` должен быть элемент с именем type, а его там походу нет. надо указывать имена существующих элементов. А если вы туда хотели передать объявленную переменную type - так ее и надо было передавать, а не этот config...

Comment: @Mike, в переменной type у меня reposts. Я просто хочу этот reposts передать через переменную. Как это сделать?

Comment: Ну наверное `$('#tasks_create_box #min_price').html(type);` сложно понять что же вам на самом деле надо

Comment: @Mike, но я же привёл рабочий пример, как можно не понять то?

Comment: Ну вы в римере обращаетесь к элементу некого массива который является свойством объекта в некотором другом массиве, который является свойством объекта `config` и раз вы и в первой строке так пишете то предполагается что вы все таки из этой вереницы объектов и массивов хотите что то получить

Comment: @Mike, мне нужно обратить к элементу reposts через переменную type, в которую записан reposts. Как-то так.

Comment: Я кажется понял, вы хотели имя свойства взять из переменной ... `$('#tasks_create_box #min_price').html(config.tasks_prices['vk'][type][0]);`

Comment: @Mike, ура! Работает! А я пробовал так `config.tasks_prices['vk'].[type][0]` и не понимал, почему не работает. Спасибо огромное! Напишите ответом :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотели передать имя свойства через переменную... Это делается так:

```
var type = 'reposts';
$('#tasks_create_box #min_price').html(config.tasks_prices['vk'][type][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка TypeError, потому что что у вас переменная - строка, а вы обращаетесь к нему как к массиву (type[0]).

Comment: в переменной type у меня reposts. Я просто хочу этот reposts передать через переменную. Как это сделать?

Comment: Убрать type[0]. Т.е. записать просто type без [0]. Тогда вы передадите эту переменную